# Docker and Substrate with Apple Silicon/M1 Chips

Tags: polkadot, cumulus, docker

Getting qemu errors when trying to build cumulus/polkadot on the container with the official image `FROM docker.io/paritytech/ci-linux:production as builder`

```
qemu-x86_64: could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

The Rust binary you have was compiled for an amd64 (x86_64) architecture and needs the linked library. The image you are running on the Mac M1 ARM is likely the arm64v8 image and so doesn't have libraries for amd64. Since Docker for Mac sets up qemu emulation, you can likely use the amd64 image by adding the --platform flag on docker pull and docker run.

That said, emulation over amd64 will be very slow and less than ideal. You are best using an arm64 image. I have personally used an ubuntu [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/ubuntu/) successfully