# How to install Substrate using Docker on an Apple M2 chip?

Tags: substrate-node-template, macbook, m2, apple

I am using a new Apple M2 laptop for Substrate development but I cannot install Substrate on it. If I follow the instructions at https://docs.substrate.io/install/macos/ it says I can install Rust and set up a Substrate development environment on Apple macOS computers with either Intel or an Apple M1 processor.

I have otherwise verified that the laptop meets the basic requirements. It is running:

- `sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string` outputs `Apple M2 Max`
- `/usr/bin/arch` outputs `arm64`
- macOS 13.4
- 12 CPU cores, 30 GPU cores (CPU usage <10%)
- 64 GB RAM (at least 20 GB RAM is free)
- 1.8 TB available space

I run the following:

- `brew update && brew --version` it outputs `Homebrew 4.1.5`
- `brew install protobuf openssl make`

Then I checked if Rosetta 2 was running by checking if running the command `pgrep oahd` output a process id, which it did.

But I ran the command `softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license` to install Rosetta 2 again anyway, and it output:

```bash
023-08-21 00:21:21.246 softwareupdate[52504:6762410] Package Authoring Error: 032-84877: Package reference com.apple.pkg.RosettaUpdateAuto is missing installKBytes attribute
Install of Rosetta 2 finished successfully
```

Then I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate#getting-started) to install Substrate using Docker with the latest Docker Desktop version 4.22.0 (117440) installed and running. I clone the Substrate repository as follows, and ran the script to install Substrate within a Docker container, where the latest Substrate commit was 94be94be6d26becd2395b58ae09ca31f596afe7d

```bash
git clone https://github.com/paritytech/substrate
cd substrate
./docker/build.sh
```

But it outputs the following error:

```bash
Building parity/substrate:latest docker image, hang on!
[+] Building 2602.6s (14/15)                                                                                                              docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from substrate_builder.Dockerfile                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.88kB                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 136B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                                                           5.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/paritytech/ci-linux:production                                                                                 3.1s
 => [builder 1/4] FROM docker.io/paritytech/ci-linux:production@sha256:dc9abf9e877c5bad94828245406dac8a186530e1ad6a1b5f2072e5e19e1f64b4                   0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:33a5cc25d22c45900796a1aca487ad7a7cb09f09ea00b779e3b2026b4fc2faba                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                         0.6s
 => => transferring context: 46.95MB                                                                                                                      0.6s
 => CACHED [builder 2/4] WORKDIR /substrate                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 3/4] COPY . /substrate                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 4/4] RUN cargo build --locked --release                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/substrate /usr/local/bin                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 3/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/subkey /usr/local/bin                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 4/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/node-template /usr/local/bin                                                        0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 5/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/chain-spec-builder /usr/local/bin                                                   0.0s
------
 > [stage-1 3/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/subkey /usr/local/bin:
------
------
 > [stage-1 4/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/node-template /usr/local/bin:
------
------
 > [stage-1 5/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/chain-spec-builder /usr/local/bin:
------
substrate_builder.Dockerfile:21
--------------------
  19 |     COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/subkey /usr/local/bin
  20 |     COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/node-template /usr/local/bin
  21 | >>> COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/chain-spec-builder /usr/local/bin
  22 |
  23 |     RUN useradd -m -u 1000 -U -s /bin/sh -d /substrate substrate && \
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 4b02f120-ba24-4d54-b2be-a38dc6dce883::kor4q7o2o99zc2mscfob9bp7v: "/substrate/target/release/chain-spec-builder": not found

real    43m22.870s
user    0m4.775s
sys 0m4.250s
```

So I then decided to run iTerm2 using Rosetta 2, by following the steps suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/428769/163511), as listed below:

- Finder > Applications and found iTerm.app (alternative to Terminal app)
- Right-clicked iTerm.app and selected "Duplicate"
- Rename the duplicate to "iTerm x86_64"
- Right-clicked "iTerm x86_64.app" > Get Info > Enabled checkbox called "Open using Rosetta".
- Double-clicked "iTerm x86_64.app" to open the Rosetta terminal instead of the native `arm64` terminal, typed `arch` and it output `i386` (i was expecting it to output `x86_64` instead)
- Right-clicked "iTerm x86_64.app" in the Dock and clicked "Keep in Dock"
- Changed to the same directory where Substrate had been cloned and ran:

```bash
./docker/build.sh
```

It was outputting:

```bash
...
=> => # <jemalloc>: MADV_DONTNEED does not work (memset will be used instead)
=> => # <jemalloc>: (This is the expected behaviour if you are running under QEMU)
...
```

And it output the following error:

```bash
Building parity/substrate:latest docker image, hang on!
[+] Building 4493.6s (14/15)                                                                                        docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 136B                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from substrate_builder.Dockerfile                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.88kB                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                                     4.5s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/paritytech/ci-linux:production                                                           2.5s
 => [builder 1/4] FROM docker.io/paritytech/ci-linux:production@sha256:dc9abf9e877c5bad94828245406dac8a186530e1ad6a1b5f2072e5e19e1  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                   0.1s
 => => transferring context: 322.12kB                                                                                               0.1s
 => CACHED [stage-1 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:33a5cc25d22c45900796a1aca487ad7a7cb09f09ea00b779e3b2026b4fc2fa  0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 2/4] WORKDIR /substrate                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 3/4] COPY . /substrate                                                                                          0.0s
 => [builder 4/4] RUN cargo build --locked --release                                                                             4488.6s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/substrate /usr/local/bin                                     0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 3/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/subkey /usr/local/bin                                         0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 4/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/node-template /usr/local/bin                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 5/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/chain-spec-builder /usr/local/bin                             0.0s
------
 > [stage-1 3/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/subkey /usr/local/bin:
------
------
 > [stage-1 4/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/node-template /usr/local/bin:
------
------
 > [stage-1 5/6] COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/chain-spec-builder /usr/local/bin:
------
substrate_builder.Dockerfile:21
--------------------
  19 |     COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/subkey /usr/local/bin
  20 |     COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/node-template /usr/local/bin
  21 | >>> COPY --from=builder /substrate/target/release/chain-spec-builder /usr/local/bin
  22 |
  23 |     RUN useradd -m -u 1000 -U -s /bin/sh -d /substrate substrate && \
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 4b02f120-ba24-4d54-b2be-a38dc6dce883::kor4q7o2o99zc2mscfob9bp7v: "/substrate/target/release/chain-spec-builder": not found

real    74m53.824s
user    0m10.714s
sys 0m9.167s
```

Update:

- I tried following the suggestion mentioned [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/82/83) of adding the option `--platform linux/arm64` [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/docker/build.sh#L16) when running `docker build` and `docker run` but i got the same error.
- I also tried a custom Docker build [here](https://github.com/ltfschoen/substrate/pull/3) where I pull from [arm64v8/ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/ubuntu/) instead of ubuntu:23.04, but I got the same error

Comment: so i removed lines 8-33 in the substrate_builder.Dockerfile https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/docker/substrate_builder.Dockerfile and i was able to enter the Docker container with `docker run -it parity/substrate` but the /substrate/target/release directory only contained the `substrate` binary, but not the `subkey`, `node-template`, or `chain-spec-builder` binaries too like it used to, hence the error. so it does build `substrate` on an Apple M2, but the question now is why doesn't it generate the `subkey`, `node-template`, or `chain-spec-builder` binaries too anymore

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error wasn't because I was using an Apple M2 chip, it was simply because for some reason if you build Substrate with Docker using substrate_builder.Dockerfile by following the instructions it now only generates the `substrate` binary in `/substrate/target/release/substrate`, but it no longer also generates the `subkey`, `node-template`, or `chain-spec-builder` binaries too like it used to.

So I think a pull request to the Substrate repository may be required to either change line 6 of [substrate_builder.Dockerfile](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/docker/substrate_builder.Dockerfile#L6) to instead run the following to generate all the binaries in the /substrate/target/release directory, so it doesn't generate an error when they are used later on lines 19-21:

```bash
RUN cargo build --locked --release && \
    cargo build -p subkey --release --locked && \
    cargo build -p node-template --release --locked && \
    cargo build -p chain-spec-builder --release --locked
```

So to overcome the error I simply removed lines of code 8-33 in the file [substrate_builder.Dockerfile](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/docker/substrate_builder.Dockerfile), and then entered the Docker container with the command `docker run -it parity/substrate` where I could then run the `substrate` binary with `./target/release/substrate --help` and manually generate the other binaries by running:

```bash
cargo build -p subkey --release --locked && \
cargo build -p node-template --release --locked && \
cargo build -p chain-spec-builder --release --locked
```

Then I was able to use those binaries too with:

```bash
./target/release/subkey --help
./target/release/node-template --help
./target/release/chain-spec-builder --help
```

Note that another approach to obtaining the latest `subkey` binary is by running:

```bash
curl https://getsubstrate.io -sSf | bash -s -- --fast
cargo install --force subkey --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate
subkey --help
```

Note that the `chain-spec-builder` binary is a *"utility to easily create a testnet chain spec definition with a given set of authorities and endowed accounts and/or generate random accounts"*, and differs from the Substrate binary command `build-spec` that you may run with `./target/release/substrate build-spec --help` is used to *"serialize the chain specification into a JSON file"*.